# Show where teenagers fight against each other in holographic worlds

Tags: story-identification

When I was younger (circa 2010) I watched a show that was in the future with there were teenagers who would pull up holographic screens and the map selector would spin and then they would be transported in the world and they would fight each other there with monsters(?)

It’s not *Code Lyoko*. I think it might have been on boomerang or another channel like that.

Comment: Live-action? Animated? Japanese Anime?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MonsSeries is a possible place to search.